# Map large user mode buffer to kernel space with get_user_pages and vmap

Tags: c, memory, linux-kernel, kernel, driver

We have streaming video camera. API is implemented as user mode library, it passes *ioctl*s to get camera info, grab video frames, etc.

Also we have two threads - each has separate file pointer. One thread passes commands, another one grabs video frames. From driver point of view some requests can be executed in parallel, while other request need to be serialized.

In the driver we want to map input and output user buffers to kernel space to avoid using `copy_to_user`, `copy_from_user` functions.

Output buffer that holds video frame can be pretty large: more than 5 Mb, it will span nearly 2462 pages.

The idea is to allocate storage for user pages for each file pointer that we have and map user buffers inside ioctl. Here is the code:

```
#define PAGES_REQUIRED(size)            (PAGE_ALIGN(size) / PAGE_SIZE)
#define PAGES_ADDR(ptr)                 ((PAGE_ALIGN(ptr) > ptr) ? (PAGE_ALIGN(ptr) - PAGE_SIZE) : ptr)

#define BUFFER_IN_MAX                   10000
#define BUFFER_OUT_MAX                  (FRAMEINFO_SIZEF + MAX_FRAME_SIZE_16)

typedef struct _FILE_CONTEXT
{
    PDEVICE_CONTEXT context;
    struct page *in_pages[(PAGES_REQUIRED(BUFFER_IN_MAX) + 1)];
    struct page *out_pages[(PAGES_REQUIRED(BUFFER_OUT_MAX) + 1) + (PAGES_REQUIRED(BUFFER_IN_MAX) + 1)];
} FILE_CONTEXT, *PFILE_CONTEXT;

struct user_packet
{
    int in_size;
    unsigned char *in_buffer;
    int out_size;
    unsigned char *out_buffer;
};

bool device_user_buffers_share_pages(uint8_t *user_addr_in, size_t user_size_in,
                                    uint8_t *user_addr_out, size_t user_size_out)
{
    uint8_t *user_page_addr_in = PAGES_ADDR((size_t)user_addr_in);
    size_t user_aligned_size_in = user_size_in + (user_addr_in - user_page_addr_in);
    uint8_t *user_page_addr_out = PAGES_ADDR((size_t)user_addr_out);
    size_t user_aligned_size_out = user_size_out + (user_addr_out - user_page_addr_out);
    return ((user_page_addr_in < (user_page_addr_out + user_aligned_size_out)) &&
            (user_page_addr_out < (user_page_addr_in + user_aligned_size_in)));
}

status_t device_map_user_buffer(/*in*/uint8_t *user_addr, /*in*/size_t user_size, /*in*/bool read_only,
                           /*out*/struct page **out_user_pages, /*out*/size_t *out_user_pages_maped,
                           /*out*/uint8_t **out_kernel_base, /*out*/uint8_t **out_kernel_addr)
{
    LogDebug("user_addr: %llu", user_addr);
    LogDebug("user_size: %llu", user_size);
    uint8_t *user_page_addr = PAGES_ADDR((size_t)user_addr);
    LogDebug("user_page_addr: %llu", user_page_addr);
    size_t user_page_offset = user_addr - user_page_addr;
    LogDebug("user_page_offset: %llu", user_page_offset);
    size_t user_pages_required = PAGES_REQUIRED(user_size + user_page_offset);
    LogDebug("user_pages_required: %llu", user_pages_required);
    size_t user_pages_pined = get_user_pages_fast(user_page_addr, user_pages_required, read_only ? 0 : 1, out_user_pages);
    LogDebug("user_pages_pined: %llu", user_pages_pined);
    if (user_pages_pined < user_pages_required) goto error;
    uint8_t *kernel_base = vmap(out_user_pages, user_pages_pined, VM_MAP, PAGE_KERNEL);
    LogDebug("kernel_base: %llu", kernel_base);
    if (!kernel_base) goto error;
    *out_user_pages_maped = user_pages_pined;
    *out_kernel_base = kernel_base;
    *out_kernel_addr = kernel_base + user_page_offset;
    return s_success;
error:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < user_pages_pined; ++i) put_page(out_user_pages[i]);
    return s_fail;
}

void device_unmap_user_buffer(/*in*/struct page **user_pages,
                                 /*in*/size_t user_pages_maped,
                                 /*in*/uint8_t *kernel_base)
{
    vunmap(kernel_base);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < user_pages_maped; ++i) put_page(user_pages[i]);
}

status_t device_open(struct inode *pinode, struct file *pfile)
{
    int minor;
    struct usb_interface *interface;
    PDEVICE_CONTEXT DeviceContext;
    PFILE_CONTEXT FileContext;

    minor = iminor(pinode);
    interface = usb_find_interface(&g_driver, minor);
    if (!interface) return s_dev;
    DeviceContext = usb_get_intfdata(interface);
    if (!DeviceContext) return s_dev;
    FileContext = heap_alloc(sizeof(*FileContext));
    FileContext->context = DeviceContext;
    pfile->private_data = FileContext;
    return s_success;
}

status_t device_close(struct inode *pinode, struct file *pfile)
{
    heap_free(pfile->private_data);
    pfile->private_data = NULL;
    return s_success;
}

long device_ioctl(struct file *pfile, unsigned int IoControlCode, unsigned long arg)
{
    status_t status;
    bool sequential;
    ERROR_CODE errCode;
    size_t szBytestoReturn = 0;
    struct user_packet packet;
    PFILE_CONTEXT FileContext;
    PDEVICE_CONTEXT DeviceContext;
    size_t inSize = 0, outSize = 0;
    uint8_t *inBuf = NULL, *outBuf = NULL;
    size_t inPages = 0, outPages = 0;
    uint8_t *inBase = NULL, *outBase = NULL;

    FileContext = pfile->private_data;
    if (!FileContext) return s_dev;
    DeviceContext = FileContext->context;
    if (!DeviceContext) return s_dev;

    copy_from_user(&packet, (unsigned char*)arg, sizeof(packet));

    // for now we don't test if user buffers actually overlap

    if (packet.in_size > BUFFER_IN_MAX) packet.in_size = BUFFER_IN_MAX;
    if (packet.out_size > BUFFER_OUT_MAX) packet.out_size = BUFFER_OUT_MAX;

    bool in_ok = packet.in_buffer && packet.in_size && access_ok(VERIFY_READ, packet.in_buffer, packet.in_size);
    bool out_ok = packet.out_buffer && packet.out_size && access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, packet.out_buffer, packet.out_size);
    bool share = in_ok && out_ok && device_user_buffers_share_pages(packet.in_buffer, packet.in_size,
                                                                   packet.out_buffer, packet.out_size);
    if (!share)
    {
        LogDebug("Not shared region {");
        if (in_ok)
        {
            inSize = packet.in_size;
            status = device_map_user_buffer(packet.in_buffer, packet.in_size, true,
                                          FileContext->in_pages, &inPages, &inBase, &inBuf);
            if (!status_success(status))
            {
                LogDebug("device_map_user_buffer failed");
                return status;
            }
        }
        if (out_ok)
        {
            outSize = packet.out_size;
            status = device_map_user_buffer(packet.out_buffer, packet.out_size, false,
                                  FileContext->out_pages, &outPages, &outBase, &outBuf);
            if (!status_success(status))
            {
                LogDebug("device_map_user_buffer failed");
                return status;
            }
        }
        LogDebug("}");
    }
    else
    {
        LogDebug("Shared region {");
        uint8_t *begin = (packet.in_buffer < packet.out_buffer) ? (packet.in_buffer) : (packet.out_buffer);
        uint8_t *end = ((packet.in_buffer + packet.in_size) < (packet.out_buffer + packet.out_size)) ? (packet.out_buffer + packet.out_size) : (packet.in_buffer + packet.in_size);

        inSize = packet.in_size;
        outSize = packet.out_size;
        status = device_map_user_buffer(begin, end - begin, false,
                                       FileContext->out_pages, &outPages, &outBase, &outBuf);
        if (!status_success(status))
        {
            LogDebug("device_map_user_buffer failed");
            return status;
        }

        if (packet.in_buffer < packet.out_buffer)
        {
            inBuf = outBuf;
            outBuf = inBuf + (packet.out_buffer - packet.in_buffer);
        }
        else
        {
            inBuf = outBuf + (packet.in_buffer - packet.out_buffer);
        }
        LogDebug("}");
    }

    // do ioctl like this:
    // switch (IoControlCode)
    // {
    // case A:
    //     errCode = ioctlA(DeviceContext, inBuf, inSize, outBuf, outSize, &szBytestoReturn);
    //     break;
    // }
    // if (errCode == ERR_NO_ERROR) status = szBytestoReturn;
    // else status = GetSystemStatusByErrCode(errCode);

    if (inBase) device_unmap_user_buffer(FileContext->in_pages, inPages, inBase);
    if (outBase) device_unmap_user_buffer(FileContext->out_pages, outPages, outBase);

    return status;
}
```

When we issue *ioctl*s that require one user page, everything works fine. However when we try to grab multiple video frames things become weird and eventually we hit segmentation fault.

The reasons why we don't wont to use `copy_to_user`, `copy_from_user` functions:

1. We want code that also works on Windows.
2. 16-bit frame must be converted to 8-bit frame in-place, so this approach   will lead us to the situation where we need to call `put_user` function for each frame word, that will be pretty slow.

Can you help me to understand what's wrong with the above code?

Comment: Do you mark modified pages as "dirty" (by calling `set_page_dirty_lock()` for example) before you call `put_page()` to release them?

Comment: @Ian Abbott It seems like parallel request were arriving with the same file pointer, so we can't allocate storage for struct page inside file context. After this fix segmentation fault is gone, and it appears to work both without set_page_dirty and with set_page_dirty. However I'm not sure what to do if input and output buffers happen to share page, whether to check for this condition or not.